# Could not resolve project :testmodule

Tags: android

Im using **Android Studio 3.0.1**

graddle: **gradle-4.6-all**

I created a module with empty body structure, when i try to add `compile project (:testmodule)` to my **app** build.gradle and sync, it keeps saying `could not resolve project :testmodule`

This is my **app** *build.gradle*

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.krot.aidltest"
        minSdkVersion 22
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
           minifyEnabled false
           proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile project (':testmodule')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
}
```

This is my module **(testmodule)** *build.graddle*

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.testmodule"
        minSdkVersion 22
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
}
```

I have tried some methods but it didn't work, please help.

Comment: Read https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/add-app-module.html

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26351138/3395198

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, i have found the answer for my question. It's because when i tried to `New module ...` I picked the option **`Phone & Tablet Module`**. In fact, it must be **`Android Library`** (next to the Phone & Tablet Module) instead the first option.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use implementation in place of compile.

```
implementation project (':testmodule')
```

**Edit** - Try the following options.

1. Build > Clean Project.
2. Build > Rebuild Project.

Comment: I tried this way too, but i still did not work for me.

Comment: Cleaning a sync helped. Thanks